# Read in JSON file from Python after opening a webpage

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, selenium-webdriver

I need to read in a json file contained in this page:

https://www.cia.gov/resources/world-leaders/page-data/sq/d/3159235335.json

And convert it to a pandas dataframe.

I have written this code:

```
chromedriver_path = r"./driver/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
url = "https://www.cia.gov/resources/world-leaders/page-data/sq/d/3159235335.json"

browser.get(url)
```

This opens the web page, but how do I actually convert it into a pandas dataframe?

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Why are you using a webdriver / browser for that at all?? Just download the file using e.g. `requests`. Or give the url directly to pandas, it can handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is not to use selenium but **requests** scrape the txt contained in it. Create a JSON file with the text, then convert the JSON into a pandas DataFrame.

Here's a link explaining the above: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-convert-json-into-a-pandas-dataframe-100b2ae1e0d8

Example Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
link = requests.get('https://www.cia.gov/resources/world-leaders/page-data/sq/d/3159235335.json')

file = open('file.json','w')
file.write(link.text)
```

Refer to this link when writing to the JSON file as the data must be indented correctly: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#